# Retrofit image download works but the file is always corrupted

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp, storage-access-framework

Here is my Retrofit API:

```
@GET
suspend fun downloadMedia(@Url url: String): Response<ResponseBody>
```

Here is the code that actually downloads the image from the URL and saves it to the device storage:

```
override fun downloadMedia(url: String): Flow<RedditResult<DownloadState>> = flow {
    preferences.downloadDirFlow.collect {
        if (it.isEmpty()) {
            emit(RedditResult.Success(DownloadState.NoDefinedLocation))
        } else {
            // Actually download
            val response = authRedditApi.downloadMedia(url)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val treeUri = context.contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions.firstOrNull()?.uri
                treeUri?.let { uri ->
                    val directory = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri)
                    val file = directory?.createFile(
                        response.headers()["Content-Type"] ?: "image/jpeg",
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""))
                    file?.let {
                        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(file.uri)?.use { output ->
                            response.body()?.byteStream()?.copyTo(output)
                            output.close()
                            emit(RedditResult.Success(DownloadState.Success))
                        }
                    } ?: run {
                        emit(RedditResult.Error(Exception("Unknown!")))
                    }
                }
            } else {
                emit(RedditResult.Error(IOException(response.message())))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file downloads and is the correct size in MB, but it somehow becomes corrupted with dimensions of 0x0 and just a blank image (when on my PC it can't even be opened).

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong as the file is being created and written to fine (which was difficult with SAF in and of itself).

Edit: I've also tried with and without `@Streaming` on the API function with the same results.

Comment: `correct size in MB,` In MB is not enough. Every byte counts. Please tell file size in bytes. Of both.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was being an idiot. I was using a `Retrofit` instance which was using a `MoshiConverter`, this caused the content length to be changed and therefore the file was corrupted. Solved by using a `Retrofit` instance without a `MoshiConverter`.